# Interacting with dev tools while scraping with nightmare.js with .evaluate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools, electron, nightmare

I am trying to automate a process that I manually perform in devtools. In the dev console I'll create a variable object:

`var api = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('apiFactory')`

and then make calls on the `api` object `api.getData(arg)` and then get returned an object `{}`

How can I get the returned object like above in nightmare's .evaluate function similarly below?

```
vo(run(arg)) 
   .then(function(result) {
   console.log(result);   
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
}); 

var run = function * (arg){ 
   nightmare.goto('https://...')

   var result = nightmare.evaluate((arg) => {
      var api = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('apiFactory')
      return api.getData(arg);     
   },result);

   yield nightmare.end();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to assume that AngularJS application wasn't bootstrapped yet at the moment when injector is retrieved.

A delay can be provided to the code inside `evaluate`, either manually set `setTimeout` or ready event listener:

```
   var result = yield nightmare.evaluate((arg, done) => {
      angular.element(() => {
        var api = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('apiFactory')
        done(api.getData(arg));
      });
   },result);
```

Or it can wait for application bootstrap:

```
   var result = yield nightmare.wait('.ng-scope').evaluate((arg) => {
      var api = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('apiFactory')
      return api.getData(arg);     
   },result);
```

Waiting for `ng-scope` class [won't work in production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688483/angularjs-class-ng-scope-is-not-being-added), in this case application-specific selectors should be waited instead.

Comment: I don't have Nightmare at hand to try this, but this is somewhat expected, because `evaluate` callback is browser scope and everything else is Node; it cannot pass the object by magic. It depends on what this data is, but generally you may want to serialize it inside `evaluate` with JSON.stringify and then deserialize with JSON.parse.

Comment: Right. So when I do stringify I'm return `'{"$$state":{"status":0}}'` Do you have any idea why i'm not getting a status 1

Comment: It's a promise. You omitted service implementation in your question, but it's so. Chain it with `then` before serializing and returning it with `done`